# Condition for multiplying columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to multiply the first column with each subsequent second column with some condition.
The main condition is to have 10 in the first row. Below you can see my data.

```
df<-data.frame(  
  Stores=c(10,30,10,0,10),
  Value1=c(10,10,0,100,0),
  Value2=c(10,10,0,100,0),
  Value3=c(10,0,0,0,0),
  Value4=c(10,10,0,0,0)
)

df
```

So multiplying values works well with this command but without any condition.

```
df[,1] * df[seq(3,ncol(df), by = 2)]
```

Now I want to put a condition for the first row of data. I tried with this command below but is not work well.

```
ifelse(df[,1]==10,1,0) * df[seq(3,ncol(df), by = 2)]
```

So can anybody help me how to solve this and to multiply values only if the first column with the title `Stores` is number 10?

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 0):

You can extend your selection with `df$Stores == 10` e.g.

```
df[df$Stores == 10, 1] * df[df$Stores == 10, seq(3, ncol(df), by = 2)]
  Value2 Value4
1    100    100
3      0      0
5      0      0
```

If you want to keep the structure of the data frame try this approach using `dplyr`. Since you can select ranges very specifically with `dplyr` the column wise condition can be changed to the variable name plus the variable number, i.e. `paste0("Value", seq(2, 4, 2))` which equals "Value2" and "Value4".

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(n = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(Value1:Value4) %>% 
  mutate(is = Stores == 10, 
         value = if_else(is & name %in% paste0("Value", seq(2, 4, 2)), 
           value * Stores[is][1], value)) %>% 
  pivot_wider(c(Stores, n)) %>% 
  select(-n)
# A tibble: 5 × 5
  Stores Value1 Value2 Value3 Value4
   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
1     10     10    100     10    100
2     30     10     10      0     10
3     10      0      0      0      0
4      0    100    100      0      0
5     10      0      0      0      0
```